# AttributeError: 'DataGenerator' object has no attribute 'shape' when I use data generators with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I use datagenerator below, learned from [https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly)

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):

def __init__(self, file_list,batch_size):
    """Constructor can be expanded,
       with batch size, dimentation etc.
    """
    self.file_list = file_list
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.on_epoch_end()

def __len__(self):
  'Take all batches in each iteration'
  return int(np.floor(len(self.file_list) / self.batch_size))

def __getitem__(self, index):
    'Generate one batch of data'
    # Generate indexes of the batch
    indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

    # Find list of IDs
    list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

    # Generate data
    X, y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)

    return X, y

def on_epoch_end(self):
    'Updates indexes after each epoch'
    self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.file_list))

def __data_generation(self, file_list_temp):
    'Generates data containing batch_size samples'
    loc = os.path.abspath('.')
  # Generate data
    for ID in file_list_temp:
        x_file_path = os.path.join(loc, "target",ID)
        y_file_path = os.path.join(loc, "newlabel",ID)

        # Store sample
        X = np.load(x_file_path)

        # Store class
        y = np.load(y_file_path)

    return X, y
```

I call it using:

```
batch_size=32
training_generator = DataGenerator(train,batch_size)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(val,batch_size)    
bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(reduction='sum')
EPOCHS =10
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./training/20220317.h5',compile=False)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss = weightedLoss(100),metrics=['accuracy'])   
H = model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
validation_data=validation_generator,epochs=EPOCHS)
```

But when I run the script, it keeps saying :

```
AttributeError: 'DataGenerator' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I tried from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils import Sequence to fix it, but it doesn't work. What should I do to deal with this error?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I change `from keras.utils import Sequence`to `from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence`
and I use `model.fit(x=training_generator)`
instead of  `model.fit_generator`